# How do I cite some specific section of wiki but not the whole page?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

For example here is the wiki page of [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax).

```
[MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)
```

This is how to cite the whole page, but how do I only cite the 'Features' section ?
(If I click the link, it automatically go down to the section.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will just mention that Wikipedia articles can change over time. So if the exact version is important for your question, you might also add a link to the current revision of the article. To do this, you can click on "View History" and from there you get to links to various revisions of the article. A bit more detailed explanation can be found here: [Is there a way to permalink a section of a Wikipedia page?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3135)

Comment: As an example, here is a link to the [ current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MathJax&oldid=923074704) of the Wikipedia article MathJax and here is link specifically [to the Features section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MathJax&oldid=923074704#Features) in that revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the link in Wikipedia's table of contents. This will change the URL in your web browser to something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax#Features. Use this link with the `#`.

Alternatively, you can right click on the link in the table of contents and use the "Copy Link Location" button or its equivalent in your preferred web browser.

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question on [webapps.se]: [How can one link to a specific portion of Wikipedia article?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92151)